# How to calculate a variable using a lagged value using R

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have a simple dataset

```
df <- data.frame(id=c("A","B","C","D","E","F"),
                 value=c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

I want to recode value (or create a new variable) so that each subsequent value is equal to the previous value * 2 + the previous value.

```
| id | value |
|----|-------|
| A  | 1     |
| B  | 3     |
| C  | 9     |
| D  | 27    |
| E  | 81    |
| F  | 243   |
```

I thought I could do this using lag:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(value=(lag(value)*2)+lag(value))
```

But that didn't work.  So instead I used a for loop

```
for (i in 2:nrow(df)){
  df[I,"value"] <-(df[i-1,"value"]*2)+df[i-1,"value"]
}
```

That works but seems inelegant.  Is there a better way to do this using tidyverse conventions/tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `accumulate` from `purrr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
     mutate(value = accumulate(value, ~ .x * 2 + .x))
#  id value
#1  A     1
#2  B     3
#3  C     9
#4  D    27
#5  E    81
#6  F   243
```

Or more compact

```
df %>%
     mutate(value = accumulate(value, ~ .x* 3))
```

---

Or in `base R` with `Reduce`

```
Reduce(function(x, y)  x * 2 + x, df$value, accumulate = TRUE)
#[1]   1   3   9  27  81 243
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `accumulate` from `purrr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(value = purrr::accumulate(value[-n()], ~.x * 2 + .x, 
                .init = first(value)))

#  id value
#1  A     1
#2  B     3
#3  C     9
#4  D    27
#5  E    81
#6  F   243
```

Which can be done similarly in base R using `Reduce`

```
Reduce(function(x, y) x * 2 + x, df$value[-nrow(df)], init = df$value[1], 
       accumulate = TRUE)
#[1]   1   3   9  27  81 243
```